# MongoCollection.watch() does not watch instantly

Tags: java, mongodb, changestream

It seems that the watch is not acting instantly, the following code only outputs inserts after sleeping a bit. How can i wait until the Change Stream is connected?

```
public class Mongodb4Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoCollection<Document> col = XXX;
        ChangeStreamIterable<Document> watch = col.watch();

        new Thread(() -> {
            col.insertOne(new Document("key", "val1"));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            col.insertOne(new Document("key", "val2"));
        }).start();

        for (ChangeStreamDocument<Document> change : watch) {
            if (change.getUpdateDescription() != null)
                System.out.println(change.getUpdateDescription().getUpdatedFields());
            System.out.println(change.getOperationType());
            System.out.println(change.getFullDocument());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the problem: i need to get the iterator first:

```
public class Mongodb4Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoCollection<Document> col = XXX;
        ChangeStreamIterable<Document> watch = col.watch();
        MongoCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<Document>> iterator = watch.iterator();

        new Thread(() -> {
            col.insertOne(new Document("key", "val1"));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            col.insertOne(new Document("key", "val2"));
        }).start();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ChangeStreamDocument<Document> change = iterator.next();
            if (change.getUpdateDescription() != null)
                System.out.println(change.getUpdateDescription().getUpdatedFields());
            System.out.println(change.getOperationType());
            System.out.println(change.getFullDocument());
        }
    }
}
```